# Play button in table view cells shows the wrong videos as it does not get the correct cell

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, uitableview

I have a table view controller where I am playing videos on click of a button in a cell.

When I try to play the video in the first cell it plays the video in the second cell.

I am assuming the problem is because it is not able to recognise the correct cell to play the video in.

Following is my code

```
var cell : ViewTableCell?

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {


        let resusableIdentifier: String = "ViewControllerCell"
        cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: resusableIdentifier) as? ViewTableCell)

        if cell == nil {
            cell = ViewTableCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: resusableIdentifier)
        }

        cell?.videoName.text = ArtistFeeds.sharedInstance.videoFeeds[indexPath.row].videoTitle


        cell?.playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TrendViewController.onTapPlayButton), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell?.playButton.tag = indexPath.row

        cell?.videoView.bringSubview(toFront: (cell?.videoName)!)
        return cell!
    }
    func onTapPlayButton(sender: subclassedUIButton){

        let indexOfButton = sender.indexPath
        let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource:ArtistFeeds.sharedInstance.videoFeeds[indexOfButton!].videoUrl, ofType:"mp4")

        let path = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: url!)
        let currentCell = trendTableView.cellForRow(at: indexOfButton) as! ViewTableCell
        currentCell.videoPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: path)
        currentCell.startPlayback()

    }
```

The above code plays the videos correctly when I play it in cellForRowAt indexPath function

When I try to play on click of a button it plays the videos in different cells.

Also in the onTapPlayButton() I get the following error

Cannot convert value of type 'Int?' to expected argument type 'IndexPath'

Any help will be appreciated . Thank you.

Below is the updated code

```
class ViewTableCell: UITableViewCell {
var avPlayer: AVPlayer?
    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
    var paused: Bool = false
    var videoPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem? = nil {
        didSet {

            avPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: self.videoPlayerItem)
        }
    }

    var tapAction: ((ViewTableCell) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func playButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        tapAction?(self)
    }
func setupMoviePlayer(view:UIView){
        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: self.videoPlayerItem)
        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
        avPlayer?.volume = 3
        avPlayer?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        avPlayerLayer?.frame = view.bounds
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer!, at: 0)

        let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 2)
        avPlayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using :{ (progressTime) in
            let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)

            if let duration = self.avPlayer?.currentItem?.duration{
                let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
                self.videoSlider.value = Float(seconds/durationSeconds)
            }
        })

    }

    func stopPlayback(){
        self.avPlayer?.pause()
    }

    func startPlayback(){
        self.avPlayer?.play()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setupMoviePlayer(view: videoView)
        // Initialization code
    }
}
```

Ad ViewController class

```
var cell : TrendViewTableCell?
var currentCell = TrendViewTableCell()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        //MARK CellForRowAt


        let resusableIdentifier: String = "ViewControllerCell"
        cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: resusableIdentifier) as? ViewTableCell)

        if cell == nil {
            cell = ViewTableCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: resusableIdentifier)
        }

        cell?.videoName.text = ArtistFeeds.sharedInstance.videoFeeds[indexPath.row].videoTitle
        cell?.tapAction = { (cell) in

            self.onTapPlayButton(cell)

        }
        cell?.playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TrendViewController.onTapPlayButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell!
    }

func onTapPlayButton(_ selectedCell:ViewTableCell){

        if let index = self.trendTableView.indexPath(for: selectedCell){
            //put your code to execute here
            let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource:ArtistFeeds.sharedInstance.videoFeeds[index.row].videoUrl, ofType:"mp4")

            let path = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: url!)
            currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as! ViewTableCell
            currentCell.videoPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: path)
            let playImage = UIImage(named: "image_video_play") as UIImage?
            let pauseImage = UIImage(named: "image_video_pause") as UIImage?
            if currentCell.avPlayer?.rate == 1.0 {
                currentCell.stopPlayback()
                currentCell.playButton.setImage(playImage, for: .normal)

            } else {
                currentCell.startPlayback()
                currentCell.playButton.setImage(pauseImage, for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
```

In the above updated code when I play a video and scroll the table view , the same video plays in the third cell from the cell in which the video is currently playing.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do to remedy this situation is add a delegate within the UITableViewCell. Make sure the protocol inherits "class", and make the delegate "weak" in order to prevent a reference cycle. You would set the delegate within the cellForRowAt delegate function and add/remove the play button within the cell itself. Whenever the button is hit, the delegate will notify the class that contains the UITableView by passing the row #, id of the movie, or whatever you feel is suitable for your needs. You can then open the correct movie.

Comment: Can you provide me an example of this @Jay

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

In your cell class:

```
class MyTVCell: UITableViewCell {

//var to hold closure that will be used for button action
var tapAction: ((MyTVCell) -> Void)?

@IBAction func myButtonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        //use var defined above as a closure to execute
        tapAction?(self)
    }
}
```

In cellForRowAt:

```
//setup cell button
        // Assign the tap action which will be executed when the user taps the UIButton
        cell?.tapAction = { (cell) in
//call your custom function
                self.mySelectedCell(cell)
            }
```

Add custom function:

```
//MARK: Button in Cell
func mySelectedCell(_ selectedCell:MyTVCell){
    //get cell index
    if let index = self.myTableView.indexPath(for: selectedCell){
        //put your code to execute here
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer should explain what problem exists in the original code and then explain how this answer solves the issue. Don't just post code with no explanation of any kind.

Comment: @maddy there are comments in the code to explain each part.

Comment: Again, you need to explain what was wrong and how this code solves the issue.

Comment: On click of the play button the videos play correctly but when I scroll down the same video plays in other cells also.

Comment: can you update your question to show how you implemented it?

Comment: I see this line of code in your update `currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as! ViewTableCell`  This looks suspect to me. Why do you need to setup this cell? You should be able to use the `selectedCell` that was passed in.

Comment: @A.S  Sir you found any Solution ? I am facing the same issue